# Meaning of "deal" in "My disastrous exam results dealt the coup de grâce to my university career."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I cannot understand the example sentence in the definition of the 1st meaning of [coup de grâce in Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/coup-de-grace?q=coup%20de%20gr%C3%A2ce).

1. Please explain about the meaning of "deal" which is used in past simple form in the sentence.
2. Is the verb "deal" transitive or intransitive here?

Besides oxford, I looked at [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deal) and [cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-german/deal?q=dealt) but couldn't find a meaning that makes sense in the sentense.

Here is the excerpt from the dictionary with the example sentence in bold face:

> coup de grâce **noun**
>
> 1.an action or event that finally ends something that has been getting weaker or worse
>
> - **My disastrous exam results *dealt* the coup de grâce to my university
>   career.**

For example in [Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/deal_1?q=deal) and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deal) overally there are three meanings for "deal" with the third meaning only appearing in cambridge:

1. **to give cards to each player in a game of cards:** He dealt me two aces.
2. **to buy and sell illegal drugs:** He was sent to jail for dealing drugs to his friends.
3. **to do business:** We only deal with companies which have a good credit record:

I also looked at [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deal) and It has 11 meanings but I couldn't relate any meaning to the mentioned sentence.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster 2:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deal) **ADMINISTER, DELIVER** - *dealt him a blow*. [Cambridge:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deal)  *deal a blow to sb/sth (also deal sb/sth a blow)* - to cause someone or something, usually a plan or hope, to fail or to be affected very badly. *The latest trade figures have dealt a severe blow to hopes of an early economic recovery.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lexico gives the following minor sense of "deal"

> inflict (a blow) on (someone or something).

It is used idiomatically with words like "punch", "cut", or "damage".

> The boxer was dealt a blow to the head.

It is clearly transitive. The direct object is "the coup de grace".

Comment: It also has a secondary, supporting meaning. It can be seen in the sense of a bad card being dealt to a card player.